Maximal property of c-cyclically monotone sets
Let $X$ and $Y$ be finite sets and $c:X\times Y\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a real cost function. A subset $\Gamma\subseteq X\times Y$ is $c$-cyclically monotone if for all $n$ and $\{(x_i,y_i)\}_{i=1}^n\in \Gamma$,
$\sum_{i=1}^n c(x_i,y_i)\leq \sum_{i=1}^n c(x_i,y_{i+1})$
where $y_{n+1}\equiv y_1$.
A subset $\Gamma$ is maximal $c$-cyclically monotone if it is $c$-cyclically monotone for any $(x,y)\notin \Gamma$, $\Gamma\cup \{(x,y)\}$ is not $c$-cyclically monotone.
Is the following conjecture true in general? (It is easy to see for the case $c(x,y)=(x-y)^2$ or more generally super/submodular functions)
Suppose $|X|,|Y|\geq 2$. For any $c$ and any $T:X\rightarrow Y$, the set $\{(x,T(x))|x\in X\}$ is not maximal $u$-cyclically monotone.
